# Django slots + foreign key save silently fails

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, save

I have found that when Django2.0 model has ForeignKey and mixin with slots it's .save() method doesn't work. While it's quite specific case, it is still kinda surprising, because there is no any Exception, data is just not saved. Here is an example:

```
from django.db import models


class FooSlots:
    __slots__ = ["bar", "value"]


class Bar(models.Model):
    pass


class FooSloted(models.Model, FooSlots):
    value = models.FloatField(default=0.42)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="foo_sloted"
    )

def check_sanity(source, bar, value=0.5):
    instance = source.objects.create(bar=bar)
    instance.value = value
    instance.save()
    instance = source.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    assert instance.value == value # Must be true!
```

So

> check_sanity(FooSloted, Bar.objects.first())

will raise assertion error, because data won't be saved, but there is no exceptions from Django itself. Even more confusing that in case bar is not a ForeignKey, but e.g. a CharField, everything is ok. Also when slots are not specified, there is no such problem too.

Is there any explanation for such behavior?

PS. To make this example less fictional: I have several "Foo"-like models with keys to different "Bar" which are populated in similar way elsewhere. FooSlots is used to enforce same interface and to treat given data for different Foo in a same way.